# flutter web refersh problem using get.rootdelegate

Tags: flutter

in my project using getx.rootdelegate for Navigation and when I navigate from main screen to Other screen pass a argument to another page and new page with this argument has been created and when refresh the page show me a message your argument is null.
and i used the package flutter web reaload decetor and when reload the package navigate to this page with same argument i have access in this screen...
but again say your argument is null...
i try to solve this issue with many different way but until i can not solve this.